# Allow user to create can bus without sudo

Tags: linux, sudoers, socketcan

I am using socketcan and virtual can buses in my application. In order to create a virtual can bus I use the command:

```
sudo ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan
```

However, is it possible to do this on a specific user account without `sudo`?

I have tried adding a line to the sudoers file using visudo, but without the desired result. I added the line `"user" ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan`, where `"user"` is the user I want to give access.

How can I get this to work?